# Laravel JWT return data from two tables

Tags: database, laravel-5, jwt

I am using JWT authentication via api.php

when a user login to the route

```
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
```

he reached this method in auth controller

```
protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {

        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 1000,
            'user' => auth()->user()
        ]);
    }
```

Here `'user' => auth()->user()` is returning the data from user table,
I have another table user_Details in which all user information is saved, I want to fetch details from that table to when some one login,

Help me out please.

Comment: Make a relationship on the user model. For example userDetails() . In your controller you can then do auth()->user()->userDetails.
This is pretty basic, i suggest you read the docs first: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find another simple way to do that

```
protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {

        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 1000,
            'user' => auth()->user(),
            'user_detail' => user_detail::where('user_id','=',auth()->user()->id)->get()
        ]);
        }
```